# FCK Editor's FileBrowser doesn't work anymore

Tags: drupal-6, hosting, fckeditor

I have Drupal 6 website which is using FCK Editor as HTML editor.

It was working **2 years fine** until yesterday, when web hosting company did some changes and since then I am getting error message:

"The server didn't reply with a proper XML data. Please check your configuration."

every time I click "Browse server" button to open built-in file browser.

This very site is **(downloaded the very very same source files & database)** however working fine on my local webserver as well as on colleague's different web hosting, so it is definitely issue of web hosting setup.

*Drupal log entry:*

**Type:** page not found
**Location:** http://*mysite*/sites/*mysite*/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php?ServerPath=%2Fsites%2Fmysite%2Ffiles&Command=GetFoldersAndFiles&Type=Image&CurrentFolder=%2F&uuid=1331667359844
**Referrer:** http://*mysite*/sites/*mysite*/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=/sites/*mysite*/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php&ServerPath=/sites/*mysite*/files

Is there some solution I can use except change editor or hosting?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's prefered to use ckeditor than fckeditor it's more stable . may be the problem happened on updating drupal core or check file sizes permission may be it reached maximum size. http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor .

Comment: Changing of editor is my second option - this web is fairly complex. I didn't update Drupal core (I didn't touched this web at all almost year), it has happened after some updates on hosting was done (I have not clue what they did). There is plenty of webspace on hosting and FCK Editor is not counting space used.

Permissions haven't been changed as well, writing permissions granted for Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by Web Hosting provider. It was wrong setup of XML in Apache.